# Forms are in Classic Style Every Run

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have my design like this
[image]

But every run it shows like a classic windows style like this
[image]

I tried putting

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles()
```

But it cant seem to solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: If called manually (rather than using the VB Framework, `EnableVisualStyles` must be invoked before you reference any UI element

Comment: Thanks for the response, so that means? How do I get it done?

Comment: Are you starting your application with this by any chance? `Application.Run(myForm)`

Comment: Show the code used to start your app -  we dont live inside your computer

Comment: Nope, I call forms by using Form1.Show()

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it, The `Form1.Show()` is changed with `Form1.Visible=true` , and I dont know why. So I changed it back to `Form1.Show()` and everything's fixed.